# Is this function inequality true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inequality

Let $\lambda$ and $\lambda_L$ be the values of the function $f(x,y)$ at the optimum for problems 
\begin{align}
\lambda=\max_{x}\min_{y}f(x,y) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lambda_L=&\max_{x}\min_{y} f(x,y) \\& \mbox{s.t.}~~g(y)=c
\end{align}
respectively. We can assume that $x$ and $y$ comes from the same domains in both problems. Is $\lambda\geq \lambda_L$?

Comment: Is your definition for $\lambda_L$ $$\lambda_L = \max\{\min\{f(x,y) : y \in D \text{ and } g(y) = c\} : x \in D\},$$ where $D$ is the domain of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, actually the opposite inequality should be true, that is $$λ\le λ_L$$ To see that, fix $x\in \mathbb R$. Then minimization of the function $f(x,\cdot)$ with respect to $y$ over a larger set, i.e. $$\{y\in \mathbb R: g(y) \in \mathbb R\}$$ (which of course includes the case $g(y)=c$), yields a minimum that is less or (at most) equal to the minimum of the function on a subset of that set, i.e. on the subset $$\{y\in \mathbb R: g(y)=c\}\subset \{y\in \mathbb R: g(y) \in \mathbb R\}$$

Therefore we have that $$\min_{y:g(y) \in \mathbb R}f(x,y)\le \min_{y:g(y)=c} f(x,y) \tag 1$$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$, which implies also that $$λ=\max_{x}\min_{y:g(y) \in \mathbb R}f(x,y)\le \max_{x}\min_{y:g(y)=c} f(x,y)=λ_L \tag 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\mathbb R$ to be the domain of $x$ and $y$ and let

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{1+x^2},
$$

$g(y) = y$, and $c = 1$.